# CSV - Issue with .append and .difference and empty lines

Tags: python, csv

I'm having a couple of weird issues with my code, if anyone could help.

```
import re
import csv
#import pdb
#pdb.set_trace()

# Variables
newStock = "newStock.csv" #csv file with list of new stock
allActive = "allActive.csv" #csv file with list of all active
skusToCheck= []
totalNewProducts = 0
i = 0

found = []
leftOvers =[]

# Program Start - Open first csv
a = open(newStock)
csv_f = csv.reader(a)

# Copy each row into array thingy
for row in csv_f:
    skusToCheck.append(row[0])

# Get length of array
totalNewProducts = len(skusToCheck)

# Open second csv
b = open(allActive)
csv_f = csv.reader(b)

# Open blank csv file to write to
csvWriter = csv.writer(open('writeToMe.csv', 'w'), delimiter=',',
                       quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
csvWriter2 = csv.writer(open('found.csv', 'w'), delimiter=',',
                        quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)

# Check first value in first row,first file against
# each entry in 2nd row in second file
with open(allActive, 'rt') as b:
    reader = csv.reader(b, delimiter=",")
    for row in reader:
        if len(row) > 1:
            for sku in skusToCheck:
                if sku == row[1]:
                    found.append(sku)
                    csvWriter.writerow(row) # write matching row to new file
                    break

# Create sets to compare
found1 = set(found)
skusToCheck1 = set(skusToCheck)

# Populate leftovers with the leftovers
leftOvers.append(skusToCheck1.difference(found1))

# write leftovers to a new file
csvWriter2.writerow(leftOvers)

# Output to screen results
print("-" * 80)
print('Added: ', len(found))
print(" ")
print(found)
print(" ")
print("-" * 80)
print('Not Found: ', len(leftOvers))
print(" ")
print(leftOvers[])
print(" ")
print("-" * 80)
```

Problems:

1. `csvWriter.writerow` (line 46)
   **Expected**: Outputs rows to csv file, row after row, with no spaces in between the rows.
   **Actual**: Output all the data I ask for, but adds a blank line between each entry.
2. `leftOvers.append(skusToCheck1.difference(found1))` (line 54)
   **Expected**: Append the difference between the two lists to leftovers
   **Actual**: Appends the list but all to one cell.

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Any specific section i should be looking at?

Comment: It's not that long, read and follow the whole thing. We also expect the code to be **in the question**, not on PasteBin.

Comment: It'd also help if you put a "problem statement" - what are you trying to achieve and why this doesn't work as expected

Comment: I have added the problems im facing with expected/actual results.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are on windows

try adding lineterminator='\n' after delimiter=',' in your write statement

ie:

```
with open('c:/some.csv', "w") as fp:
    a = csv.writer(fp, delimiter=',', lineterminator='\n')
    data = ['some','data']
    a.writerow(data)
```

if you want to append to the file use "a" for append instead of "w" for write.